# ARM template transform array of strings into array of objects

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

Not sure if this functionality exists. I'm trying to transform a list of comma separated IP addresses from the Azure DevOps build parameters into an array of objects. So far it's only splitting a comma separated list into an array of strings, but the template needs an array of objects.

The parameter value is a comma separated list of IP Addresses.
e.g. "**192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2/32,127.0.0.1**"

The ARM template would look like:

```
"variables": {
  "ipaddresses": "[split(parameters('ipaddresses'), ',')]"
},
"resources": [
  ...
    "ipRestrictions": "[stringArrToObjArr(variables('ipaddresses'))]" <--
  ...
]
```

And ideally function with the arrow above would yield a value for ipRestictions would be something like:

```
[
  {
    "ipAddress": "192.168.0.1"
  },
  {
    "ipAddress": "192.168.0.2/32"
  },
  {
    "ipAddress": "127.0.0.1"
  },
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `copy()` function to do that:

```
"variables": {
  "ipaddresses": "[split(parameters('ipaddresses'), ',')]"
  "copy": [
    {
      "name": "myVariable",
      "count": "[length(variables('ipaddresses'))]",
      "input": {
        "ipAddress": "[variables('ipaddresses')[copyIndex('myVariable')]]"
      }
    }
  ]
},
```

this would return the desired object into a variable called `myVariable`. if you want to rename it >> don't forget to rename it inside `copyIndex()` as well

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Weird how it's called input, not output though.